# Server triggers the client

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

I'm working on a Client-Server program, and i need to start the client from the server, is there any idea to make this?

Thank you for you answers.

Regards.

Comment: if there is an estableshed connection between C/S then your client could wait for response from the server by trying to read from the inputStream. if not , you need a third party that will communication with the server and start the client.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a `separate program/Wrapper` that will be connected to your server and will listen to the messages from your server and then on a specific message will run your client.